# ASP.NET Perform Calculation in Stored Procedure, or in Databind in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, gridview

Hey so I have a stored procedure populating a gridview

and in my stored procedure I have two columns such as

```
Total_Price DataType Money
```

and

```
Discount DateType decimal(18, 0)
```

and I want to display a derived column called `Actual Price` which is

```
Total_Price - Discount
```

is it best to create this column in the stored procedure or calculate on load in the gridview ?

Heres my stored procedure at the moment

```
    SELECT     f.supplier_name,d.product_ID_key, d.product_name AS productName, d.packsize, d.tradePrice, d.IPU_code, d.EAN_code, c.discount, e.stock_indicator
FROM         aw_customer AS a INNER JOIN
                      aw_cust_contract AS b ON a.cust_ID_key = b.cust_ID_key INNER JOIN
                      aw_contract_line AS c ON b.contract_ID_key = c.contract_ID_key INNER JOIN
                      aw_product AS d ON c.product_ID_key = d.product_ID_key INNER JOIN
                      aw_stock AS e ON d.product_ID_key = e.product_ID_key INNER JOIN
                      aw_supplier AS f ON d.supplier_ID_key = f.supplier_ID_key
WHERE     (a.cust_ID_key = @customerId)
ORDER BY d.product_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would calculate this at Stored Procedure level, so that any calls to this Stored Procedure would return the same results (you haven't got to do the math on other gridviews etc in the future if they are calling the same Stored Procedure)

In situations like this, I've often created a `SQL View` so that the calculations are done within the view, and then multiple Stored Procedures can call this View and display the data like:

```
SELECT Total_Price
       ,Discount
       ,Actual_Price
FROM [v_TableA]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214068%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

See this article for details of Indexing Views, which will also improve performance:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx

Comment: hey see my stored procedure in original post, am I best of putting that in a view will that improve speed etc ?

Comment: Like @sll has stated, executing the calculation db level will enhance performance over running the calculation within the Bind of the GridView. However, I think storing the query in the view wouldn't make much difference as the query is still ran either way. I think what i like about storing it in a view is that its consistent data output, you won't have loads of duplicate calculation throughout the system. For example, if the `Actual_Price` is affected by another column in the future, you will have to go through all your stored procedures and change the calculation.

Comment: Also an alternative would be to create a User Defined Function. But basically, to answer your initial question, running the calculation db level would be better than the bind of the GridView at application level.

Answer (score 0):

Any way doing this on the data base level (in SP) will significantly improve a performance of data calculation but on other hand adding a new column increases a network load due to increased data amount.

So decide yourself what is more important for your application.